# Spring additional information with authentication request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring web application that's currently using HTTP Basic authentication, using a username and password, passed in the header. I want to add additional fields to be passed in with the authentication request, including an (optional) security answer and a device id. I want to switch to passing this information inside of the request body, such that I can easily extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

I have this in WebSecurityConfig:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{        
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(permitAllUrls)
        .permitAll();

    http
        .addFilterAt(new MobileUserAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

    http.logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/");

    http
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/**")
    .hasRole("USER")
    .and()
    .csrf()
    .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new NoAntPathRequestMatcher(nonCsrfUrls))
    .and()
    .addFilterAfter(new CsrfGrantingFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class);
}
```

`MobileUserAuthenticationFilter` is (currently) an empty class that extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. Sending a request to the login endpoint successfully calls the `attemptAuthentication` method of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`. However, the request body being received appears to be empty.

This is the internals of `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` (unnecessary code omitted for clarity):

```
public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY = "username";
public static final String SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY = "password";

private String usernameParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_USERNAME_KEY;
private String passwordParameter = SPRING_SECURITY_FORM_PASSWORD_KEY;

public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    if (postOnly && !request.getMethod().equals("POST")) {
        throw new AuthenticationServiceException(
                "Authentication method not supported: " + request.getMethod());
    }

    String username = obtainUsername(request);
    String password = obtainPassword(request);

    if (username == null) {
        username = "";
    }

    if (password == null) {
        password = "";
    }

    username = username.trim();

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            username, password);

    // Allow subclasses to set the "details" property
    setDetails(request, authRequest);

    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(authRequest);
}

protected String obtainUsername(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return request.getParameter(usernameParameter);
}

protected void setDetails(HttpServletRequest request,
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authRequest) {
    authRequest.setDetails(authenticationDetailsSource.buildDetails(request));
}
```

Stepping through this reveals that the `request` argument of `attemptAuthentication` contains no parameters (it's calling `request.getParameter("username")`). Adding the debug expression `request.getParameterNames()` returns an empty enumeration.

My outgoing request is:

```
{ 
    debugId: 1,
    uri: 'http: //localhost:8080/login',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 
        host: 'localhost: 8080',
        accept: 'application/json',
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'content-length': 49
    },
    body: '"{\\"username\\":\\"3\\",\\"password\\":\\"password1\\"}"'
}
```

But username and password are both null when reaching the filter. What am I missing, is there something I need to add to allow the filter to accept a request body?